# How Do I enable ftp in Mac OX Lion

Tags: mac, macos, ftp

I recently updated my Snow Leopard installation to Lion, and I couldn't ftp into my localhost. I went into the system preferences pane > sharing > file sharing > options and looked for the FTP option. It's not there! Apple has removed the FTP option from the GUI, so you now have to enable it through terminal. I had to wait on tech support to get that answer, so I figure I'd help someone else out. Someone like me is bound to run into this issue. Here's the link to the article they sent me that fixed the issue: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4704?viewlocale=en_US.

Note: In step three, you need to add yourself again, even if you are the admin user that was put in step one.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to answer your own quesiton, but if you do so, please ask the question as if you didn't know the answer, and then post your solution as an answer so that others can find it in the future.